# Is there a way to get an integer on howmany values there are in a hashmap with the same key?

Tags: java, hashmap

For school i'm building a multiplayer game. In this game I have a list of players in the lobby. This list contains the id of the player and the spritename of the player. Thoose are my values. As key i'll put the key of the lobby. together the form the Hashmap i'm working with.

When i want to connect to the lobby I have to know if the player allready is in the hashmap so I need a foreach loop to check that. But i don't know how to do that or even if that is possible.

```
private HashMap<Integer, List<String>> playersInLobby;

public IRemotePublisherForListener connect(int playerID, String spriteName, int lobbyID) 
{
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; playersInLobby.containsKey(lobbyID);)
    {
        if (playersInLobby.get(lobbyID).get(0) == playerID + "")
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        playersInLobby.put(lobbyID, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(playerID + "", spriteName)));
    }
    return publisher;
}
```

Comment: `values in hashmap with the same key`, only 1. You can't have duplicate key in a hashmap, that is the point ;)

Comment: Your `put`-logic is quite far off as well - that way there can only be ever at most one player in every lobby. And what is `publisher` and what kind of for-loop is that supposed to be? Are you right now trying to prevent players to be in a lobby twice or to be in two lobbies at the same time?

Comment: You can use [Guava Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) for your purposes

Comment: Don’t use `==` for comparing strings. Use `.equals()`.

Comment: luk2302 yes i'm trying to prevent that yes. And the publisher is a class thats bin givven by school to simplify the rmi connection. (Yes I know. All my classmates hate RMI including me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be simpler to solve and reason about if you had more abstraction. If you made a `Map<Integer, Lobby>` which maps the lobby ids to lobbies, as well as a `Player` class which aggregates the id and sprite name. It would be simply:

```
private final Map<Integer, Lobby> lobbiesByID;

private boolean isPlayerInLobby(Player player) {
    return lobbiesByID.values().stream().anyMatch(l -> l.hasPlayer(player));
}

public IRemotePublisherForListener connect(Player player, int lobbyID) {
    if(!isPlayerInLobby(player)) {
        //.. insert null-check unless you trust the id
        lobbiesByID.get(lobbyID).addPlayer(player);
    }
    //.. else, log an error, or throw
    return publisher;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch, I can use this.